# How to pass a radio button value of a table from one jsp to another

Tags: java, jsp

i have a 2 JSP pages
i.adminhome.jsp
ii.deletecontroller.jsp

adminhome.jsp shows the client table

i want the admin to delete a specific row from the client table if he so desires.
so i need to use a radiobutton to select the clientid from the client table, and press the "Delete" button to delete that selected row

But i am not getting the desired output as i am failing to pass the selected clientid value to the deletecontroller page as a session variable. Thus i am getting null value.

These are the codes of the 2 pages

1.adminhome.jsp

```
<%
try
{
Connection conn=null;
Statement stmt=null;
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:xyz","sa","pass");
stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select UserID,Username,Location,Gender,EmailID from Client");

while(rs.next()){%>


<table border="1" align="center" >
    <tr>
        <td><input name="district" type="radio"  value="<%=rs.getString("UserID") %>" required="true"/></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("Username") %></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("Location") %></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("Gender") %></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("EmailID") %></td>


        <%  
            String x = request.getParameter("district");
            session.setAttribute("userid", x);
        %>




        <td><input type="submit" name="btn1" value="Delete"></td>

    </tr>
</table>

        </div>

        <br/><br/>



<%}
}
catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

%></form>
```

2.deletecontroller.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>
<%
    String x=session.getAttribute( "userid" ).toString();
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:xyz;","sa","pass");

    Statement stmt=null;
    stmt = con.createStatement();

    String del="Delete from Client where UserID='"+x+"' ";
    stmt.executeUpdate(del);

    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");



%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's just go through what your code does

```
 <td><input name="district" type="radio"  value="<%=rs.getString("UserID") %>" required="true"/></td>
...
<%  
 String x = request.getParameter("district");
 session.setAttribute("userid", x);
%>
```

You are outputting an HTML form with a field called district. And at the same time you are reading district from the request and saving it to the session.  Since district isn't in the request, you are reading a NULL, and saving NULL in the session.  How would it be in the request when you are just now outputting the form?  The user can't submit the form before you've output the form to the user, can they?

Then when you submit the form, in your servlet you are reading from the session:

```
String x=session.getAttribute( "userid" ).toString();
```

You are reading the NULL you saved into the session when you were building the form. You are not reading the form that the user actually submitted.

What should you be doing?   Reading from the request in the servlet:

```
String x = request.getParameter("district");
```

The request with a parameter district is generated when the user submits the form, so the request is being sent to the servlet and you should read from the request there.

Or, another way would be to save to the session from the `rs.getString("UserID")`:

```
<% 
  session.setAttribute("userid", rs.getString("UserID")); 
%>
```

That might be what you want, since UserID probably is something that should be session scope rather than request, and since you don't want the user changing their userid in the form and manipulating things. Then you can still read from the session in your servlet.

Comment: i have tried ur solution, instead of reading the value with a String x variable i have saved the session using

    <% 
      session.setAttribute("userid", rs.getString("UserID")); 
    %>

but still its showing NULL :(

Comment: Also i am seeing whenever i am including this line
<% 
  session.setAttribute("userid", rs.getString("UserID")); 
%>
the Client table is only showing the 1st row, instead of all the rows of the Client table

Comment: Lol. I didn't notice the loop.  You need to really think through what you're doing because almost all of it is wrong. Not trying to be rude, just the truth.  You can't have a form with multiple instances of the same name.  It just won't work.  You will need to append numbers to your field names for each row (I.e. `<input name="district_1".../>...<input name="district_2".../>`) or find a better way to do this.

Comment: And now that I read your question again, you obviously should not be using the session.  Use the request object.  You want to submit one form with all the rows checked that you want deleted, right?  So append numbers to the fieldnames for each row, add a field at the end (outside the loop) to tell how many rows there are, and in your servlet read that number from the request, and loop through and read the fields for that many rows, and delete the rows where they were checked.

Comment: Finally did it, didnt use session variable, took a textbox where the admin will give the userid and click the delete button to delete that client from the table :D